# Is <body>.onLoad called before rendering is done?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call some JS after the page-load, this may involve a delay and as such I want the page loaded first so content is shown... but it seems that the code in onLoad handler is called *before* the rendering is complete. Is there a better event I can use, which is triggered when the page is 'finished'?

To clarify, I want to run some JS after the page is rendered on-screen, so a 'post-everything event' really.

Comment: If your page fully renders and then your Javascript manipulates the DOM, you will have a "flash" of the unmanipulated DOM and then the change will show up.  But onload should only be called after all images are downloaded, etc...

Comment: So.... you want to run your code after the DOM is ready or after all resources are loaded. Sorry, but this is not clear to me.

Comment: basically after I see the page in front of me, I then want to run some code.

Comment: @John "onLoad handler is called before the rendering is complete." As far as I know after "onload" you'll find layout decided and all element structures completed. What experience makes you think otherwise? Other signals are "ondomcontentloaded" and "onpageshow". But maximum cross-browser compatibility militates against them, because many versions of many browsers don't fire them (especially "onpageshow", which is generally restricted to the "bfcache" feature). The jQuery generalization takes care of cross-browser issues, but note well it's for "DOM Ready", _not_ for displaying completed.

Answer (score 7):

There are several points of interest along the time sequence. This generic sequence is a good overview, even though different browsers and versions implement the details a little differently. (This assumes you're using raw Javascript and need to minimize cross-browser issues; with it's comprehensive internal handling of cross-browser issues JQuery is a little different):

T0] page-begun-- The browser has started working on the page, but otherwise the environment is in flux. Your JS operations may occur in the wrong context, and simply be flushed away when the right context stabilizes. You probably don't want to try to execute any JS at all.

T1] "onLoad" event-- [however you get events: addEventListener("Load"..., window.onload=..., etc.] All parts of the page have been identified and *downloaded*  from the server and are in the local system's memory. In order for all parts to be identified, some parsing has already occurred. (Note that "load" is a cognate of "download", not "parse" nor "render".)

You now have the right environment and can begin to execute JS code without fear of losing anything. *HOWEVER*, operations that try to read or manipulate the HTML [getElementById(..., appendChild(..., etc.] may fail in strange ways, or may appear to work but then disappear, or may do something different than you expected.

T2] DOM-*almost*-ready-- This hack is very simple and fully cross browser. Just put your JS <script>...</script> at the very end of your HTML, just before the </body> tag. Most things will work right, although attempts to append to or modify the DOM at the very end of the <body> may produce surprising results. This isn't fully correct, but it works 99% of the time. Given its simplicity and the very high probability of correct operation, this may be the way to go (at least if you don't use JQuery).

T3] DOM-ready-- [however you get events: addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"..., window.ondomcontentloaded=..., etc.] At this point the HTML has been completely parsed and JS is 100% available, including all functions that read or manipulate the HTML [getElementById(..., appendChild(..., etc.].

T4] Render-done-- The browser is finished displaying the content on the screen. There is ***NOT*** any such event or any reasonable cross-browser version-agnostic way to detect this situation. That's just as well, as you probably don't really want this anyway. If the browser has already displayed the page on the screen and *then* you manipulate the DOM, you'll get a "flash", where both the before and the after are visible on the screen at least briefly. What you probably really want is the point where you can execute arbitrary JS code; that's the *previous* (T3] DOM-ready) point in time.

Comment: Is this answer still correct?  According to [this image](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/images/summary_200.png), onLoad happens after onDOMContentLoaded.

Comment: The answer is browser- and version-dependent. The DOMContentLoaded event appears to have never been adequately standardized, and is not fired at all by many current [June 2023] browsers. IF it is fired at all, I believe it will be fired _before_ the Load event; the image referenced is wrong. To find out what any particular browser really does, start the browser of interest and point it at  https://www.ckollars.org/browser-page-events.html .

Answer (score 3):

Either attach a callback to [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload)

```
window.onload = function(){
    // your code here
};
```

this will fire when all resources are loaded (which might be not what you want).

Or put all of your code at the bottom the page (before the closing `body` tag). The code will be run when the HTML is parsed.

---

FWIW, here is the jQuery code. You see, the use custom event handlers for IE and the other browsers, but use `window.onload` as fallback:

```
// Mozilla, Opera and webkit nightlies currently support this event
if ( document.addEventListener ) {
    // Use the handy event callback
    document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", DOMContentLoaded, false );

    // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
    window.addEventListener( "load", jQuery.ready, false );

    // If IE event model is used
} else if ( document.attachEvent ) {
    // ensure firing before onload,
    // maybe late but safe also for iframes
    document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", DOMContentLoaded);

    // A fallback to window.onload, that will always work
    window.attachEvent( "onload", jQuery.ready );

    // If IE and not a frame
    // continually check to see if the document is ready
    var toplevel = false;

    try {
        toplevel = window.frameElement == null;
    } catch(e) {}

    if ( document.documentElement.doScroll && toplevel ) {
        doScrollCheck();
    }
}
```

Comment: @StuperUser: Don't know if it is raised at exactly the same point (it should according to the specification), but it is raised at a point where the DOM is available.

Comment: I already use `onLoad` and it isn't working properly in any browser I try... my basic HTML is _not_ visible when the JS gets called and since the JS is doing some heavy lifting the page stalls. This is likely bad use of JS but regardless shouldn't the page be rendered _before_ the method fires... that's what I need.

Comment: @John: Have you tried adding the code at the bottom of the HTML page? Are you sure you are setup your code correctly? Can you provide a link to your page?

Answer (score 0):

As with a lot of JavaScript this will depend on which browser you are using.

As @Avitus' answer, have you looked at the execution point of JQuery's document ready event? This has been generalised across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using a javascript library (like jQuery) I would rather go with the $(document).ready() statement which is called once the DOM is ready to be manipulated.

The other option I see would be to include your function call at the end of your HTML page so that all the HTML content would be loaded so you can afterward execute your code safely

Answer (score 0):

["The onload event waits for all binary content to download before firing. No kitty-tickilng until then."](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/06/again/)

As this post says, it is called after all binary content is downloaded, you need to listen for a ready event either using jQuery's ready, or your own function. [This project looks interesting.](http://code.google.com/p/domready/)

There are many cross browser implementations so use either jQuery or that project I linked to.

I have written my own function for my library, it uses internal methods so will not work on its own but might give you a feel for what you have to do. You can find that function [here](https://github.com/Wolfy87/Spark/blob/master/src/ready.js).