# Adding wrappers to elements, then reading offsetTop returns wrong result

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used this before for the target element, not the wrapper, but it seems like it isn't working in this example. If you run the code, you'll see some weird things. The sections offsetTops are 0, even before the wrappers added to them. The second weird thing is that it seems like the wrappers get to the very bottom, because they offsetTops are body's offsetHeight - wrapper's offsetHeight. Is the problem with that the function is called inside window.onload? I really don't know what the problem is. The closest relative positioned parent element is the body in all case of logging to the console. All the elements have display other than none. Someone please explain me what's happening here. And please don't suggest getBoundingClientRect(), because it's not the case where it is useful for me.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
  let eT = [];
  for (let i = 0, len = sections.length; i < len; i++) {
      const el = sections[i];
      console.log(el.offsetTop, el.offsetParent);
      if (el.parentNode.className !== "wrapper") {
          const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
          wrapper.className = "wrapper";
          el.parentNode.appendChild(wrapper);
          wrapper.appendChild(el);
          wrapper.style.height = el.offsetHeight + "px";
          wrapper.style.position = "relative";
      }
      const elCont = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper")[i];
      let elClone = elCont;
      eT[i] = 0;
      do {
          eT[i] += elClone.offsetTop;
          elClone = elClone.offsetParent;
      }
      while (elClone !== document.body);
      console.log(eT[i], elCont.offsetHeight, document.body.offsetHeight);
  }
}
```

```css
section{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
}
body{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
</body>
```

**EDIT**
I tried with onscroll, and everything works fine. But, it isn't explains why these things happen.

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images, scripts, links and sub-frames have finished loading. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

So it's still weird. And before I was used this function also onload, but it worked fine. I tried to add wrappers to the elements, and get they offsetTops, and then these things happened. But, in this example if I try it without wrappers, it isn't work too. And, I wasn't change anything in my previous (working) code, just added the wrappers thing.

Comment: `el.parentNode` is `body`?

Comment: In this example, as you can see, yes.

Comment: possibly a "duplicate" of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221416/is-body-onload-called-before-rendering-is-done ? I would assume reading the answer to that question at least gives you an idea where to look

Answer (score 0):

Its just the implementation issue, it is behaving as expected. Please go through below explanation

```
/**
 * Lets go through one iteration
 * Lets name our sections S1, S2, S3, S4 for brevity
 * current DOM: body<S1 S2 S3 S4>
 */

// el = S1
if (el.parentNode.className !== "wrapper") {
    const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    wrapper.className = "wrapper";
    el.parentNode.appendChild(wrapper);
    // At this point wrapper is the last child of body, with 4 sections above it
    // DOM: body<S1 S2 S3 S4 W>
    wrapper.appendChild(el);
    // el has been MOVED inside wrapper, and is removed from its original position
    // DOM: body<S2 S3 S4 W<S1>>
    wrapper.style.height = el.offsetHeight + "px";
    wrapper.style.position = "relative";
}
```

So, after adding each wrapper

1. There are 3 sections before wrapper, hence offsetTop is 3006 (1002 * 3)
2. Now that the topmost element is moved, next element is the new topmost element, so for next iteration offsetTop of the next element is 0.

Same will be repeated for all iterations. This is the reason for getting 0 offsetTop for all sections and 3006 offsetTop for all wrappers.

Hence proved.